# Pass char pointer array to function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, char

I'm trying to pass an initialized char pointer array to a function. I can't seem to figure out why the function will only print out the numeric digits of each element in the array.

Does anyone know how I can print each string element from the passed in pointer array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sort(char *);

int main()
{
   char *states[4] = {"Florida", "Oregon", "California", "Georgia"};

   sort(*states);

   return 0;
}

void sort(char *states)
{
   int x;

   for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
      printf("\nState: %d\n", states[x]); //only this will compile
      //printf("\nState: %s\n", states[x]); //need to print this.
   }

}
```

Comment: You pass a pointer to `Florida` to the function, and then print out the numbers corresponding to the first four letters of that string.  Wasn't that what you intended?

Comment: `sort(states);` and `void sort(char *states[])`

Comment: Ok, I see. So I was not accepting the array of pointers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `sort` function must accept the array of pointers if you wish to print the contents of the array.

```
void sort (char *states[], size_t num_states) {
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x < num_states; ++x) {
        printf("\nState: %s\n", states[x]); /* Note %s instead of %d */
    }
}
```

And, you must pass the array to the function.

```
sort(states, 4);
```

Comment: `sort` function must accept a pointer to pointer. Ultimately, `char *states[]` is equivalent to `char **states` as a function parameter, therefore `char *states[]` is not an array of pointers.

Comment: @haccks: You are correct. The argument from the caller was the name of an array, and the `sort` function must have a prototype that allows that argument to be passed. An array name decays to a pointer value equal to the address of its first element, so `sort` needs to accept a pointer to a `char *`.

Comment: So the char array pointer in main is always just initially pointing to the first element in that array, correct?

Comment: @user3495404; No char array pointer in `main`. `states` is an array of pointers to `char`.  In function call `sort(states, 4);`, `states` converted to `char **` (pointer to first element of array `states`, i.e pointer to `state[0]`).

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse an array of pointers to char to `sort` (instead of just pointer to char).

As jhx pointed out, you need to pass the size of the array as well. You can use `sizeof` so as to not hard-coding `4`. Also omit the array size when initialize it.

```
void sort( char *states[], int arr_size )
{
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x < arr_size; x++) 
    {
        printf( "\nState: %s\n", states[x] );
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *states[] = {"Florida", "Oregon", "California", "Georgia"};     // array of pointers to char

    sort( states, sizeof( states ) / sizeof( char * ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the sizeof(states) / sizeof(char *) is doing?

Comment: `states` is an array of pointer to char. `char *` is a pointer to char. So that division specifies the number of elements (ie, the number of char pointers) in the `states` array of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the char pointer array to the function:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void sort(char *args[], int n);

    int main()
    {
       char *states[4] = {"Florida", "Oregon", "California", "Georgia"};

       sort(states, 4);

       return 0;
    }

    void sort(char *states[], const int N)
    {
       int x;

       for (x = 0; x < N; x++) {
          printf("\nState: %s\n", states[x]); 
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that only numeric values you are getting is that only pointer to first element of string `states[0]` of the array `states` is passed, i.e. you are passing `&states[0][0]`. So, the statement

```
printf("\nState: %d\n", states[x]);
```

will only print the numeric value of first `4` characters of string `"Florida"`.

You need to pass the pointer to first element of array `states`, i.e. `&states[0]`.
This can be done by changing the declarator of function `sort` to

```
void sort(char **, size_t size); // You need to pass the size of array too.
```

and call it as

```
sort(states, sizeof(states)/sizeof(char *));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending `states` which is an `array of pointers`. So you need to send the base address of that array to the function

```
sort(*states);
```

And then receive it in an array of pointer only

```
void sort(char* states[])
{
   int x;

   for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
      printf("\nState: %s\n", states[x]);
   }

}
```

---

Hardcoding the size if also not a good idea, so better add another parameter `size` to the function call.

```
sort(states, sizeof(states)/sizeof(char*));
```

and later use that to iterate over the array

```
void sort(char* states[], int size)
{
   int x;

   for (x = 0; x < size; x++) {
      printf("\nState: %s\n", states[x]);
   }

}
```